# Exchange 2010 database log path

Tags: exchange, logging, exchange-2010, log-files

My company would like to migrate Exchange 2010's Mailbox logs to another server to centralize logging. We are aware of the wizard and tried to use it to migrate the logs over but we can across this error message:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkvM2.png)

The file path's structure is correct. Does the drive the logs are going to be moved to need to be mapped to the server? Do we need to share the disk?

Any help is appreciated and I will give any information needed. Thank you.

Comment: `My company would like to migrate Exchange 2010's Mailbox logs to another server to centralize logging.` - It looks like you're misunderstanding the purpose and use of the Mailbox Database logs. These are not activity logs, these are transaction logs. The Mailbox Database transaction logs must be in a local path, not a network path.

Comment: I don't think any of the Exchange activity logs can be stored elsewhere. They need to be local. You will need to fetch the logs from the logging server rather than have Exchange put them there. 

However as already pointed out - that will not include these transaction logs. They must stay local.